# VBA - Using criteria list select and clear or select an replace values

Tags: excel, vba, replace

Alright, I'm back. This time I'm trying to quickly select all of the values in a range which match values in a separate list, my first iteration will be to clear the contents of voided IDs, my second iteration will be to select those values and then replace them with corresponding new values.

I asked another question about VBA and was pointed in mentioning that I've tried to teach myself and find resources to work through these issues before but people seem to get pissed that I'm asking, if you could at least direct me to somewhere that I can learn about these matters (or even a place I can learn basic logic and have a list of usable functions without having to go through all the "How to make your first Excel VBA for some problem that nobody cares about" I would appreciate it)

Anyway I tried to watch a few videos and then hack together something but it seems pretty clear that the function they were using cannot be adapted for other uses. This is what I have at the moment:

```
Sub FilterElim()
    finalRow = Range("g2").End(xlDown).Row
    Range("A1").ClearContents _
        Action:= xlClearContents, _
        CriteriaRange: Range("Sheet4!B1:B10"), _
        Unique:= False
End Sub
```

So based on some helpful questions I am making an edit to include an example and desired end

Example set:
[image]

Desired end result:

[image]

I presume I may need to perform a selection of some sort based on the Criteria before the ClearContents but I wasn't finding anything helpful on how to go about that. PLEASE and thank you.

```
| Contractor   ID | Cont Name         | Proj 1 | Proj 2 | Proj 3 |   |   | Old ID | Reconciliation |
|-----------------|-------------------|--------|--------|--------|---|---|--------|----------------|
| C1001           | Boba Fet          | P1120  |        |        |   |   | P1001  | Void           |
| C1003           | Jules Winnfield   | P1031  | P1045  |        |   |   | P1002  | P1010          |
| C1002           | Dom Cobb          | P1001  |        |        |   |   | P1005  | Void           |
| C1010           | Patrick Verona    | P1020  | P1224  | P1251  |   |   | P1020  | Void           |
| C1007           | Matt Damon        | P1008  | P1005  | P1300  |   |   | P1045  | P1100          |
| C1004           | Ned Plimpton      | P1002  |        |        |   |   | P1224  | P1300          |
| C1020           | Derek Zoolander   | P1020  | P1290  |        |   |   |        |                |
| C1009           | Charles Marlow    | P1002  | P0090  |        |   |   |        |                |
| C1011           | Robert Jordan     | P1119  |        |        |   |   |        |                |
| C1015           | Perrin Aybara     | P1200  | P1224  |        |   |   |        |                |
| C1005           | Fuzzy Dunlop      | P1005  |        |        |   |   |        |                |
| C1008           | Thomas A Anderson | P1001  | P1000  |        |   |   |        |                |
|                 |                   |        |        |        |   |   |        |                |
```

Comment: Can you share some data and expected output? You can use [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to share data in a way we can copy paste formatted. When you paste the markdown table in to the question via [edit] highlight the table and press Ctrl+K to enter formatted nicely.

Comment: Ah shoot, thanks so much for responding, I read your initial question and dove right into making an example without seeing your markdown suggestion. I did make an edit, and can share a google sheet of the example if you think that's a safe way to go about it?

Comment: OK I put in a markdown table of the data

Answer (score 3):

What makes you go for a VBA solution ?
Hard to do much without a glance of you data and expected result.

Non VBA option:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($G$2:$G$15,MATCH(A32,$F$2:$F$15,0)),B32)`

[image]

For a VBA option, you can try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub update_id()

Dim D1 As Object: Set D1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Dim R1 As Range: Set R1 = Range("A2:A32")
Dim R2 As Range: Set R2 = Range("E2:E15")
Dim Rtmp As Range

For Each Rtmp In R2
    D1(Rtmp.Value) = Rtmp.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next Rtmp

For Each Rtmp In R1
    If D1.exists(Rtmp.Value) Then Rtmp.Offset(0, 1) = D1(Rtmp.Value)
Next Rtmp

End Sub
```

Working on the following set up :

[image]

Again, without a better understanding of your data and your issue, its hard to be more precise.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm not locked in on VBA, this process is something I will likely have to do several times in a variety of ways so I'm just trying to save time in the long run by creating a replicatable process and thought VBA might best facilitate that. I've included an example set and can provide access to a google sheet if you think that's a secure means of sharing

Comment: Hey O.Pal, I added some information I'm not sure that it will change your mind on approach but wanted to let you know. Best - C